# Low space problem in Unity Hub installation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded "unity hub 2.4.3.0" and installed it in my D drive, my C drive is low in space. Now I opened unity hub and went to installs and when i try to add a version (Recommended release Unity 2020.3.8.f1(Lts)) i get an error "There is not enough space to download and install the selected items". My D drive has over 400Gb free space. Why this error is popping up while my unity hub is already installed in D drive. I went into unity hub settings and in Unity editors path selected the same folder where my unity hub is installed.
[I downloaded unity hub from official site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQMUx.jpg)
[I am attaching a picture showing available installation space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqr5k.jpg)

Please need help.

Sorry for links showing instead of images as this site is not allowing me to post images as i am new and my reputation is less than 10.

Comment: Nice, you already figured it out on your own ;) Best would be you remove that comment and convert it into a proper answer :) Also note that either way Visual Studio will take a lot of space in C .. so make sure that it fits as well

Answer (score 0):

I get it done. The thing is unity saves files in your temporary folder while downloading which by default is on C drive as windows is installed there. I changed the directory of my temporary folder. here is how you can do it (https://www.howtogeek.com/285710/how-to-move-windows-temporary-folders-to-another-drive/) Now i am not an expert but maybe some apps stop working, in my case it was only unity hub so i uninstalled it and reinstalled and i was good to go. do not forget to restart pc after changing temp and tem directory